# Sublime Text 2 LatexTools: Cannot find builder

Tags: latextools

I don't know what I make wrong. I installed LatexTools exactly as described but every time I try to compile a messages shows up: "Cannot find builder traditional". I changed the builder to "simple" but same message:"Cannot find builder simple". All the solutions that I've read don't work. I use Ubuntu. I hope you can help me.

This is my LatexTools.sublime-settings:

```
 // LaTeXTools Preferences DEFAULT SETTINGS
//
// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!!! Open the Command Palette and run the "Reconfigure and migrate settings"
// command. Alternatively, select the "Reconfigure LaTeXTools and migrate settings" item from the
// Preferences, Package Settings, LaTeXTools menu, or open the ST console and type
//          sublime.run_command("latextools_migrate")
// This will migrate your old settings and create a file "LaTeXTools.sublime-settings" in your
// User directory. You can also manually copy this file to the User directory.
//
// Once the file is in the User directory, you can edit it at will.

{


// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// General settings
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Cite/ref autocompletion by default is triggered after e.g. \ref{. If you don't like this,
    // set to false. You can also use toggles: C-l,t,a,c and C-l,t,a,r.
    "cite_auto_trigger": true,
    "ref_auto_trigger": true,
    // Sometimes a \ref is preceded by an open parenthesis.
    // By default, we do not close the parenthesis after completion
    // But, if you want us to, set this to true.
    "ref_add_parenthesis": false,

    // Fill-helper autocompletion triggered for a wide range of references to external
    // files. You can also use toggle: C-l,t,a,f
    "fill_auto_trigger": true,

    // Keep focus on Sublime Text after building (true) or switch to PDF viewer (false)
    // If you are on Windows or Linux and using ST2, you may need to set the
    // "sublime_executable" setting for this to work in your platform settings.
    "keep_focus": true,
    // Sync PDF to current editor position after building (true) or not
    "forward_sync": true,

    // When to trigger cwl-command completion (requires the LaTeX-cwl package)
    // possible values are:
    // "always" (always show command completions)
    // "prefixed" (default, show command completions if the current word is prefixed with '\')
    // "never" (never show command completions)
    "command_completion": "prefixed",

    // level to hide the build panel after the build is finished
    // Possible values are:
    // "always" (hide the panel even if the build failed),
    // "no_errors" (only hide the panel if the build was successful even with warnings),
    // "no_warnings" (only hide the panel if no warnings occur) and
    // "never" (default, never hide the build panel)
    "hide_build_panel": "never",

    // valid texfile extensions
    "tex_file_exts": [".tex"],

    // controls whether or not syntax is automatically set to LaTeX for
    // files that match one of the configured `tex_file_exts`
    "latextools_set_syntax": true,

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Temporary file settings
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Ends of the names of temporary files to be deleted
    "temp_files_exts": [
        ".blg",".bbl",".aux",".log",".brf",".nlo",".out",".dvi",".ps",
        ".lof",".toc",".fls",".fdb_latexmk",".pdfsync",".synctex.gz",
        ".ind",".ilg",".idx"
    ],
    // Folders that are not traversed when deleting temp files
    "temp_files_ignored_folders": [
        ".git", ".svn", ".hg"
    ],

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Platform settings: adapt as needed for your machine
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

    "osx":  {
        // Path used when invoking tex & friends; MUST include $PATH
        "texpath" : "$PATH:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin"
        // Path to PDF viewer, if needed
        // TODO think about it. Also, maybe configure it here!
    },


    "windows": {
        // Path used when invoking tex & friends; "" is fine for MiKTeX
        // For TeXlive 2011 (or other years) use
        // "texpath" : "C:\\texlive\\2011\\bin\\win32;$PATH",
        "texpath" : "",
        // TeX distro: "miktex" or "texlive"
        "distro" : "miktex",
        // Command to invoke Sumatra. If blank, "SumatraPDF.exe" is used (it has to be on your PATH)
        "sumatra": "",
        // Command to invoke Sublime Text. Used if the keep_focus toggle is true.
        // If blank, "subl.exe" or "sublime_text.exe" will be used.
        "sublime_executable": "",
        // how long (in seconds) to wait after the jump_to_pdf command completes
        // before switching focus back to Sublime Text. This may need to be
        // adjusted depending on your machine and configuration.
        "keep_focus_delay": 0.5
    },

    "linux" : {
        // Path used when invoking tex & friends; MUST include $PATH
        "texpath" : "$PATH:/usr/bin/latexmk",
        // Command to invoke Python 2. Useful if you have both Python 2 and Python 3 on your system,
        // and "python" by default is linked to Python 3. If blank, "python" is used
        // Note: ST3 uses Python 3 internally, but the evince scripts need Python 2
        "python2": "",
        // The name of the ST2 or ST3 executable. On Ubuntu, both subl and sublime-text are
        // available for ST2; adjust as needed for other platforms, and for ST3
        "sublime": "sublime-text",
        // How long to wait after evince has launched before sending a sync message
        // in seconds, floating point; choose 2.0 or 3.0 on a slower machine, 0.5 on a fast one
        // Note: only tweak this if sync after launching the PDF viewer does not seem to work,
        // or if the PDF viewer opens instantly and you don't want to wait.
        // Default: 1.5 (works on my MBP4,1...)
        "sync_wait": 1.5,
        // Command to invoke Sublime Text. Used if the keep_focus toggle is true.
        // If blank, "subl" or "sublime_text" will be used.
        "sublime_executable": "",
        // how long (in ms) to wait after the jump_to_pdf command completes
        // before switching focus back to Sublime Text. This may need to be
        // adjusted depending on your machine and configuration.
        "keep_focus_delay": 0.5
    },

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Build engine settings
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

    // OPTION: "builder"
    // Specifies a build engine
    // Possible values:
    //
    // "default" or ""  the default built-in build engine; currently
    //                  this is the same as "traditional"
    //
    // "simple"         invokes pdflatex 1x or 2x as needed, then
    //                  bibtex and pdflatex again if needed;
    //                  intended mainly as a simple example for
    //                  people writing their own build engines.
    //
    // "traditional"    replicates the 'old' system based on
    //                  latexmk (TeXLive) / texify (MiKTeX)
    //
    // "script"         external script: just invokes the script
    //                  specified in "builder_settings"
    //
    // custom name      you can also use third-party build engines;
    //                  if so, set the "builder_path" option below
    //
    // NOTE: custom builders CANNOT have the same name as an existing
    // built-in build engine (including "default")

    "builder": "traditional",

    // OPTION: "builder_path"
    // If non-empty, specifies a path to a custom builder, relative to the
    // Sublime Text Packages directory.
    // For instance, "User/builders" (on Windows: "User\builders") is a good
    // choice if you roll your own.
    // (Note: if you choose "User", you may get a Python import error in the
    // console, but things will still work).
    // Leave empty ("") for a built-in builder.

    "builder_path": "",

    // OPTION: "builder_settings"
    // Specify builder-dependent settings and preferences
    // Possible values: see README or documentation provided with
    // third-party build engine.
    // Builder setting can be general or OS-dependent

    "builder_settings" : {

        // General settings:
        // See README or third-party documentation

        // (built-ins): true shows the log of each command in the output panel
        "display_log" : false,

        // Platform-specific settings:
        "osx" : {
            // See README or third-party documentation
        },

        "windows" : {
            // See README or third-party documentation
        },

        "linux" : {
            // See README or third-party documentation
        }
    },

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Opening files included into the tex source code
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

    // image types you use in latex
    // these types will be used for autocompletion and
    // opening of included images, when no extension is written
    "image_types": ["png", "pdf", "jpg", "jpeg", "eps"],

    // the commands to open image files. The extensions will be matched from top to bottom.
    // If no extension is given, all extensions will be matched.
    // If there is no match the image will be opened with Sublime Text.
    // the extension:
    //      can either be a string for one extension
    //      or an array of string to match more than one extensions.
    // the command:
    //      can be the name to start the programm. The image file will be passed
    //          as the argument.
    //      can be a string as a command with args:
    //          e.g. "open -a PixelMator", in this case the file will be appended
    //          if the position is relevant use "$file" in the string
    //          e.g. "open -a PixelMator $file"
    //          this will be substituted by the path to the file
    "open_image_command": {
        "osx" : [
            {
                // open pdf and eps documents with skim
                "extension": ["pdf", "eps"],
                "command": "open -a Skim.app"
            }
            // uncomment these lines to open all other images with the default programm
            // ,
            // {
            //  "command": "open"
            // }
        ],

        // You might want to use "start" for the default programm used by Windows.
        "windows": [
            {
                // open pdf and eps documents with sumatra (it has to be on your PATH)
                "extension": ["pdf", "eps"],
                "command": "SumatraPDF"
            }
            // uncomment these lines to open all other images with the default programm
            // ,
            // {
            //  "command": "start"
            // }
        ],

        "linux": [
            {
                // open pdf documents with evince
                "extension": "pdf",
                "command": "evince"
            }
            // uncomment these lines to open all other images with the default programm
            // ,
            // {
            //  "command": "xdg-open"
            // }
        ]
    },

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Formatting of bibliographic references in quick panel
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

    /* This preference sets the format of the quick panel to select citations using wildcards.
    The setting is a list with one or two string using wildcards for author, title, keyword etc.

    Default setting: the traditional display, `["{title} ({keyword})","{author}"]`
    Format:
    Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete? This is an non-existing subtitle to illustrate (einstein1935quantum)
    Albert Einstein and B Podolsky and N Rosen

    Richer alternative: ["{author_short} {year} - {title_short} ({keyword})","{title}"]
    Format:
    Einstein et al. 1935 - Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete (einstein1935quantum)
    Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete? This is an non-existing subtitle to illustrate

    Another alternative: ["({keyword}) {author_short} - {year}","{title} - {journal}"]
    Format:
    (einstein1935quantum) Einstein et al. - 1935
    Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete? - Physical Review

    No-title alternative: ["{author_short} {year} ({keyword})"]
    Format:
    Einstein et al. 1935 (einstein1935quantum)

    Valid wildcards: keyword, title, author, year, author_short, title_short, journal
    */

    // Uncomment or modify at will
    "cite_panel_format": ["{author_short} {year} - {title_short} ({keyword})","{title}"],
    //"cite_panel_format": ["({keyword}) {author_short} - {year}","{title} - {journal}"],
    //"cite_panel_format": ["{author_short} {year} ({keyword})"],

    // Similarly, the formatting for the autocomplete panel:
    "cite_autocomplete_format": "{keyword}: {title}"

}
```

Thx.

Comment: What's the output on the Sublime console when you attempt to build (ctrl+`)?

Comment: Sublime console shows nothing. It's empty.

Comment: Ok... let's try to confirm that your install of LaTeXTools actually has the required files. From Sublime select **Preferences | Browse Packages...**, which will open your Sublime Packages folder. Open the **LaTeXTools** folder and then the **builders** subfolder. You should see a file called "`traditionalBuilder.py`" and one called "`simpleBuilder.py`".

Comment: Yes, these files are in the subfolder.

Comment: I found something out. Very strange. I don't know, maybe it could be a solution. If I go in Sublime Text "Preferences | Package Settings | LatexTools and select "Settings-Default". It open an empty text file. But if I select in "Preferences | Browse Packages | LatexTools-Master | LatexTools.sublime-settings there are the settings i posted in my question.

Comment: Ah ha! The problem is that you've installed LaTeXTools in a folder called **LaTeXTools-Master**! LaTeXTools makes some (possibly faulty) hard-coded assumptions that it is in a folder called **LaTeXTools**, so if you rename the folder, things should probably work as expected.

Comment: One other thing, please don't make modifications to the `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` file in the package folder. All your changes will be overwritten any time you install an update. Please just run the **LaTeXTools: reconfigure and migrate settings** command and edit the **Settings - User** file.

Comment: Perfect, it seems that is the solution for the builder error but now it doesn't open a pdf after compile. The code in the Sublime Text console seems ok with no error message. Thx.

Comment: Just to ask the stupid question, you do have Evince installed on your machine and available at `/usr/bin/evince`?

Comment: Essentially to *launch* evince, LaTeXTools runs a command like this: `sh ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/LaTeXTools/evince/evince_sync python subl /path/to/file.pdf`. You could try running that from the terminal and seeing what the output is.

Comment: Bingo, thank you so much. That was it. Evince was not installed :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, just to document what's already in the comments:

The issue was that LaTeXTools was installed in a folder named something other than **LaTeXTools**. LaTeXTools assumes and hardcodes that the folder it is in is called **LaTeXTools**.